# JS window print margins breaked table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I have a table that i want to print using JS **window.print();**.
But when this table have too many lines oter pages dosen't preserve seted margins

[image]

My CSS:

```
@page { size:  auto; margin: 0px; }
html  { background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0px; }
body  { margin: 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm; }
tbody > td > span { font-size: 14px !important; }
```

How can I force this table breaks to preserve margins?

Click on any element to print: https://jsfiddle.net/kfubawpg/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The `top-margin` of the header on the following pages?

Comment: the margin-top and margin-bottom of breacked tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `@page` margin set to 0.  Just change it to the size of the margin you want.

```
@page { size:  auto; margin: 50px; }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfubawpg/1/)

Comment: this slove my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
    @page :first { // set the margins for the first page in print mode
      margin: 100px;
    }

    @page { // set the margins for all following pages (tables) in print mode
    size:  auto; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kfubawpg/2/)